# Oracle SQL Conditional SUM and TO_CHAR

Tags: sql

I have a table with a sum that I want to format with $ at the beginning, but it gives me an error:

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

```
select sum(TO_CHAR(a.freight, '$99,990.00')) AS "Costo total", (b.company_name) AS "Compañía fletera"
FROM orders a
inner join shippers b
on a.ship_via = b.shipper_id
group by b.company_name
order by b.company_name asc;
```

what I want is to see "Costo total" with a money format like $123.45

Comment: I think your idea is ok, but you have to sum first and then convert to char, not vice versa. Meaning "SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(a.freight),'$99,990.00')..." If this doesn't solve your problem, could you please provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Copied the comment as answer to make it possible to close the question:
Your idea is ok, but you have to sum first and then convert to char, not vice versa. Meaning "SELECT TO_CHAR(SUM(a.freight),'$99,990.00')..."